# Connecting JTable content to Java DB

Tags: java, database, swing, netbeans, jtable

1- I am Using `NetBeans 7.4 GUI Builder`, and i want to have a `JTable` that has some data. the Tutorial in `netbeans website` shows how to connect an `existing DB table` to the `Jtable`, but i want to write my own query and show the results in the JTable, how to do that?

2-when i was following the tutorial in `netbeans`, the table shows its bound to a Table in `Java DB`, but when I run the program the JTable appears empty, it has rows, but no data, is there a code i have to write to populate the data other than the steps mentioned in the tutorial?

this is a link to the [tutorial](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/gui-binding.html)

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a connection string to connect to the DB from your code. Then Run a query to fetch records from the DB table like this:

   ```
   Connection con = //create a connection string;
   Statment smt = con.createStatement();
   ResultSet rs = smt.executeQuery("Your SQL");
   ```
2. Now retrieve records from your ResultSet and populate in your Jtable

   ```
   while (rs.next()) 
       {
           //Populate table
       }
   ```

Comment: @CanadianDavid My browser has some problem so I was not able to mark codes, thanks for the edit :)

Comment: No problem! Since your code was in a numbered list, you just needed to use 8 spaces instead of 4 spaces.

Comment: hmm, I see. so i should remove the binding and do what you wrote, but iam using JPA so i think i know the relevant statments:) . But i have a few more qestions, i see some people using a 'Jtable.setModel'? so in the loop i should use it?! and lastly, this code is part of the GUI class ?